# cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors

Tags: c++, ruby, swig, gcc-warning

In system:
Fedora 21
Ruby 2.1.7
GCC 4.9.2

I follow the instructions for installing [simstring](http://www.chokkan.org/software/simstring/) but afer

> $ruby extconf.rb

when trying to make and make install, I got an error:

```
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:217: recipe for target 'export_wrap.o' failed
make: *** [export_wrap.o] Error 1
```

And the entire log of this error is bellow

[Error Log](https://gist.github.com/aliabbaC/1fdb50d8e63197d8bf5b0ae4c119fa0c)

I searched about this error but all of replies are about how to disable Werrors and configure with ignoring werrors.
Is there any solution?I think something not mentioned but i don't know what..

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hi @Barry, I already sent my full log, its in Error log text file. and also the instruction for installing simstring exists and I thought it wouldn't need to mention.. thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1):

> I searched about this error

That's not an error. It's a notification. It notifies that some warnings have been treated as errors.

> I searched about this error but all of replies are about how to disable Werrors and configure with ignoring werrors. Is there any solution?

You answered your own question. If the source code of the program generates warnings, and if the compiler is asked to treat warnings as errors, then the compiler will refuse to compile the program. Complete list of possible solutions are:

- Fix the source code to not generate warnings. This is a very good idea.
- Stop asking the compiler to treat warnings as errors (this is the solution that you already found). You should still fix the code to not generate a warning.
- Ask the compiler to ignore the warnings entirely. This is usually a bad idea unless you understand the warning and know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks, but all errors are about **Swig** e.g `Swig_Error` and `[-Werror=format-security]` and I don't know where they are generated to fix.. tnx